# Twig keyword `services` always has the value `true`

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm working in Symfony and tried to pass a variable called `$services` into my twig template. Naturally, I would also refer to the variable in twig with the same name.

```
$services = new ArrayCollection();    // Some array

$this->render('template.html.twig', [
    'services' => $services
]);
```

For some reason however, `services` always is a boolean value of `true`. This is instead of the `ArrayCollection` I am trying to pass into it.

---

I've checked my twig configuration for anything that could be assigning itself as a global variable but everything checks out, and I can't seem to find any documentation about `services` being a reserved keyword.

FWIW, I renamed the twig variable name from `services` to `foo` for sanity checking and the `$services` variable behaves as expected, so it's definitely got something to do with assigning a variable to the word `services` in twig.

I'm currently running Twig 2.14.3

Apart from checking if there are any global variables set, are there any other avenues for trying to find why and where this variable would be defined?

Comment: Cannot repro. With [this](https://cln.sh/KsluNH) and [this](https://cln.sh/cxl2rP) I get [this](https://cln.sh/lvPARM). It's possible to use the `services` twig variable name just fine. Something else must be causing this in your project. Check `debug:twig` to see if there is any global or filter defind for your application.

Comment: Hmm, strange. I ran `debug:twig` to check but nothing with the word `services` appeared at all. Nothing in the globals, functions or filters catch my attention either

Comment: Without additional info, it doesn't seem possible to debug this. As I've shown, what you mention is not reproducible on a standard Symfony installation with Twig 2 (or 3, for that matter).

Comment: Can you share more details, like the content of your template? Also, have you checked whether there are any global variables configured for Twig?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a few hours of troubleshooting, it seems like a pretty dumb answer.

I checked:

- Global variables in my `twig.yaml` configuration
- Made sure that any custom twig extensions weren't bound to `service`
- Checked that any bound services weren't creating any functions with the name `service`
- Made sure that I wasn't setting `service` in any of my templates up to my base template

It seemed like a whole lotta nothing, then I started turning to some 3rd party bundles that have some twig templates registered.

It turns out a bundle had a template with `{% set services = ... %}` written inside it, which was included in my base template.

---

+1 to @yivi for brining `debug:twig` to my attention, as it was incredibly useful knowing what is bound to twig. It was this info that made me aware of any namespaces that bundles had bound themselves to and gave some extra places to start looking.